# How do deal with multiline log files and convert to csv

Tags: python, csv

Say I have a log file that looks like this:

```
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341068 ]' LOG: SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341068 ]' LOG: SET STATEMENT_TIMEOUT TO 300000;
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341068 ]' LOG: /* hash: 720a01bd6ef3747b7f0585c0a70c01e9 */

select logtime, tbl_id, trim(tbl_name) as tbl_name, col_id, src_encode, tgt_encode, scan_rows,
case
when command_phase = 'Add shadow column complete' then 0
when command_phase = 'Reset Table Partition Manager complete' then 1
when command_phase like 'Shadow Col corrupt sorted regions%' then 2
when command_phase like 'shadow cols must contain same data%' then 3
when command_phase like 'Shadow Col not conform to range partition%' then 4
when command_phase = 'Data copy phase 1 complete' then 5
when command_phase = 'Data copy phase 2 complete' then 6
when command_phase = 'Drop existing shadow column complete' then 7
else -1
end as command_phase,
t2.metadatawritten as committed
from stl_alter_column_encode_events t1, stl_commit_stats t2
where logtime > getdate() - INTERVAL '1 day' and node = -1 and t1.xid = t2.xid;
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341068 ]' LOG: SELECT pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.logtime AS logtime, pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.tbl_id AS tbl_id, btrim( pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.tbl_name ) AS tbl_name, pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.col_id AS col_id, pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.src_encode AS src_encode, pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.tgt_encode AS tgt_encode, pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.scan_rows AS scan_rows, CASE WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase = 'Add shadow column complete'::Char(26) THEN 0 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase = 'Reset Table Partition Manager complete'::Char(38) THEN 1 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase LIKE 'Shadow Col corrupt sorted regions%' THEN 2 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase LIKE 'shadow cols must contain same data%' THEN 3 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase LIKE 'Shadow Col not conform to range partition%' THEN 4 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase = 'Data copy phase 1 complete'::Char(26) THEN 5 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase = 'Data copy phase 2 complete'::Char(26) THEN 6 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase = 'Drop existing shadow column complete'::Char(36) THEN 7 ELSE -1 END AS command_phase, pg_catalog.stll_commit_stats.metadatawritten AS committed FROM pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events, pg_catalog.stll_commit_stats WHERE pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.xid = pg_catalog.stll_commit_stats.xid AND pg_catalog.stll_commit_stats.node = -1 AND pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.logtime > getdate() - interval '1 day'::Interval;
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341068 ]' LOG: COMMIT;
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341069 ]' LOG: SET query_group to ''
```

And I want to convert to csv, how do I find an appropriate delimiter?
I want the records of the csv to be something like this where the left side is the column name and the right side of the equals sign is the value.

```
timestamp='2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC 
db=dev 
user=rdsdb 
pid=18771 
userid=1 
xid=20341068
query=SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;
```

and for the multiline query:

```
timestamp: '2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC 
db=dev 
user=rdsdb 
pid=18771 
userid=1 
xid=20341068
query='select logtime, tbl_id, trim(tbl_name) as tbl_name... t2.xid;';
```

Do I have to use a regex to create capture groups? What can I do to break this up into csv records. The problem is that sometimes the query section is on the same line and other times it's on multiple lines.

Comment: Would a quick and dirty fix to bring each entry onto a single line help?  You would still need to pick out the pieces you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

You don't "have" to use regex, though a proper regex wizard (which I am not) would likely create something less brittle.

Here is a hand parsing that might generate a `list` of `dict` to pass into a csv writer. It does not have to be `dict` based though and you potentially want to write directly as you parse rather than accumulate the results like I am doing.

```
import json

data = '''
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341068 ]' LOG: SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341068 ]' LOG: SET STATEMENT_TIMEOUT TO 300000;
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341068 ]' LOG: /* hash: 720a01bd6ef3747b7f0585c0a70c01e9 */

select logtime, tbl_id, trim(tbl_name) as tbl_name, col_id, src_encode, tgt_encode, scan_rows,
case
when command_phase = 'Add shadow column complete' then 0
when command_phase = 'Reset Table Partition Manager complete' then 1
when command_phase like 'Shadow Col corrupt sorted regions%' then 2
when command_phase like 'shadow cols must contain same data%' then 3
when command_phase like 'Shadow Col not conform to range partition%' then 4
when command_phase = 'Data copy phase 1 complete' then 5
when command_phase = 'Data copy phase 2 complete' then 6
when command_phase = 'Drop existing shadow column complete' then 7
else -1
end as command_phase,
t2.metadatawritten as committed
from stl_alter_column_encode_events t1, stl_commit_stats t2
where logtime > getdate() - INTERVAL '1 day' and node = -1 and t1.xid = t2.xid;
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341068 ]' LOG: SELECT pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.logtime AS logtime, pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.tbl_id AS tbl_id, btrim( pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.tbl_name ) AS tbl_name, pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.col_id AS col_id, pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.src_encode AS src_encode, pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.tgt_encode AS tgt_encode, pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.scan_rows AS scan_rows, CASE WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase = 'Add shadow column complete'::Char(26) THEN 0 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase = 'Reset Table Partition Manager complete'::Char(38) THEN 1 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase LIKE 'Shadow Col corrupt sorted regions%' THEN 2 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase LIKE 'shadow cols must contain same data%' THEN 3 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase LIKE 'Shadow Col not conform to range partition%' THEN 4 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase = 'Data copy phase 1 complete'::Char(26) THEN 5 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase = 'Data copy phase 2 complete'::Char(26) THEN 6 WHEN pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.command_phase = 'Drop existing shadow column complete'::Char(36) THEN 7 ELSE -1 END AS command_phase, pg_catalog.stll_commit_stats.metadatawritten AS committed FROM pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events, pg_catalog.stll_commit_stats WHERE pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.xid = pg_catalog.stll_commit_stats.xid AND pg_catalog.stll_commit_stats.node = -1 AND pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.logtime > getdate() - interval '1 day'::Interval;
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341068 ]' LOG: COMMIT;
'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=18771 userid=1 xid=20341069 ]' LOG: SET query_group to ''
'''

## -----------------------
## You can clean this up :-)
## -----------------------
def parse_log_entry(log_entry):
    ## -----------------------
    ## super brittle and crappy hand parse
    ## variable names like these not be be spoken of
    ## in polite company
    ## -----------------------
    x = log_entry.split(" [ ")
    y = x[1].split(" ]' LOG: ")
    z = y[0].split(" ")
    ## -----------------------

    return {
        "timestamp": x[0].strip(),
        "db": z[0].split("=")[1],
        "user": z[1].split("=")[1],
        "pid": z[2].split("=")[1],
        "userid": z[3].split("=")[1],
        "xid": z[4].split("=")[1],
        "query": y[1][:80] + ("..." if len(y[1]) > 80 else "")
    }
## -----------------------

nice_logs = []
prior_log_entry = ""
for line in data.splitlines():
    ## -----------------------
    ## if this is not the start of a new log entry
    ## append it to the prior good starting point
    ## -----------------------
    if not line.startswith("'2021-"):
        prior_log_entry += line
        continue
    ## -----------------------

    ## -----------------------
    ## if the prior log entry is not "empty" we
    ## can parse it to a dict and append it to our list
    ## or simply write it to our csv
    ## -----------------------
    if prior_log_entry:
        nice_logs.append(parse_log_entry(prior_log_entry))
    ## -----------------------

    ## -----------------------
    ## This entry IS the start of a new log entry to set it aside
    ## in case the next line(s) need to be appended to this one
    ## -----------------------
    prior_log_entry = line
    ## -----------------------

## -----------------------
## if the final prior log entry is not "empty" we
## can parse it to a dict and append it to our list
## or simply write it to our csv
## -----------------------
if prior_log_entry:
    nice_logs.append(parse_log_entry(prior_log_entry))
## -----------------------

## -----------------------
## At this point we can use a dict writer if
## have not already to write our CSV
## -----------------------
print(json.dumps(nice_logs, indent=4))
## -----------------------
```

This produces a list of dict that I hope you can see how might be turned into a CSV with the python csv module

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": "'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC",
        "db": "dev",
        "user": "rdsdb",
        "pid": "18771",
        "userid": "1",
        "xid": "20341068",
        "query": "SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC",
        "db": "dev",
        "user": "rdsdb",
        "pid": "18771",
        "userid": "1",
        "xid": "20341068",
        "query": "SET STATEMENT_TIMEOUT TO 300000;"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC",
        "db": "dev",
        "user": "rdsdb",
        "pid": "18771",
        "userid": "1",
        "xid": "20341068",
        "query": "/* hash: 720a01bd6ef3747b7f0585c0a70c01e9 */select logtime, tbl_id, trim(tbl_nam..."
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC",
        "db": "dev",
        "user": "rdsdb",
        "pid": "18771",
        "userid": "1",
        "xid": "20341068",
        "query": "SELECT pg_catalog.stll_alter_column_encode_events.logtime AS logtime, pg_catalog..."
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC",
        "db": "dev",
        "user": "rdsdb",
        "pid": "18771",
        "userid": "1",
        "xid": "20341068",
        "query": "COMMIT;"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "'2021-05-26T09:06:42Z UTC",
        "db": "dev",
        "user": "rdsdb",
        "pid": "18771",
        "userid": "1",
        "xid": "20341069",
        "query": "SET query_group to ''"
    }
]
```